# How do I show the value of an array that has another array inside?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, datatable

How do I loop through this array and how do I display this roleName value  want to loop through it with map

```
{ 
   "userMenuDTO": {    
        "menuId": "13",
        "menuName":"PruebaMenu900-13",
        "menuRoute":"/path/ruta900-13",
        "menuParentId":null,
         "menuDinamico": true,
        "menuEnabled": false,
        "menuPosition": 900,
        "menuIcono":"pruebaIcono",
        "roles": [
            {
                "roleId": 1,
                "roleName": "CO-MOCA-ADMIN",
                "roleType": 1
            },
             {
                "roleId": 2
                
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: its an object.  all you have to do is obj.userMenuDTO.roles.map(item => <p> {item.roleName} </p>)

Comment: you'd loop through `x.userMenuDTO.roles` - where `x` is the name of the variable that object is in ... by the way, there is only a single array, there's no array inside another array in the data you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the iteration, you can use **forEach** and **map**

```
const {roles} = userData.userMenuDTO; // Object destructuring

// forEach won't return any result so that we have to push to an array.
const result = [];
roles.forEach(role => result.push(role.roleName)); // using arrow function here
console.log(result);

// Map will return result as array. (more preferable approach)
var rollNamesArr = roles.map(role => role.roleName);
console.log(rollNamesArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this JSON object has roles array inside this and you can directly access the roles array.

You can you mapper in this case and extract role names into new array and use it, just one of many ways to do this.

```js
var userData = {
  "userMenuDTO": {
    "menuId": "13",
    "menuName": "PruebaMenu900-13",
    "menuRoute": "/path/ruta900-13",
    "menuParentId": null,
    "menuDinamico": true,
    "menuEnabled": false,
    "menuPosition": 900,
    "menuIcono": "pruebaIcono",
    "roles": [{
        "roleId": 1,
        "roleName": "CO-MOCA-ADMIN-1",
        "roleType": 1
      },
      {
        "roleId": 2,
        "roleName": "CO-MOCA-ADMIN-2",
        "roleType": 2
      },

      {
        "roleId": 3,
        "roleName": "CO-MOCA-ADMIN-3",
        "roleType": 3
      }
    ]
  }
};

var rollNamesArr = userData.userMenuDTO.roles.map(function(role) {
    return role.roleName;
});

console.log(rollNamesArr);
```